# Using OpenSSL on Windows to access REST API with authentication

Tags: c++, authentication, openssl

I would like to be able to access https://api.prosper.com/api/Listings from a win32 console application, written in Visual Studio.

I have downloaded OpenSSL from [here](https://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL-1_0_1i.exe) and found an example on how to use it [here](https://thunked.org/programming/openssl-tutorial-client-t11.html). When I use the example as is, there are no issues, but I am not sure how to modify so I can pass my user name and password (when accessing it through a browser, you get the standard modal window where you enter these, and then the page loads).

I have Googled extensively to try and find clues, but haven't been able to find anything. I should probably note that I initially wanted to use `libcurl`, but I was unable to find binaries + headers for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL only helps you with the SSL/TLS layer. "REST" typically implies HTTP so you need to either implement the entire HTTP logic yourself or use an existing library that does. Like libcurl.